# Parse Large Gzip File and Manipulate Data with Limited Memory

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, gzip

Use Case: Given a ~2GB .gz file with newline delimited json, manipulate each line and write output to zip file (csv)

Issue: The environment I am working with has ~1GB of memory and I do not have traditional access to the file system. The only way I can write to a file is by passing the entire data stream as a single object from memory (I cannot loop a generator and write to file)

My approach so far has been to loop through the data in my .gz file, modify the data, then compress it in memory and write it out after all data is processed. When I use chunking and do not manipulate the data this works. However, when I try to do this one line at a time it seems to run indefinitely and does not work.

Example gzip data:

```
{"ip": "1.1.1.1", "org": "cloudflare"}
{"ip": "2.2.2.2", "org": "chickenNugget"}
```

Note: that this is not true json, each line is valid json but this is NOT an array

Target Output:

```
value,description
1.1.1.1, cloudflare
2.2.2.2, chickenNugget
```

Example that works in a few seconds using chunking:

```
import gzip
chunksize = 100 * 1024 * 1024
with gzip.open('latest.json.gz', 'rt', encoding='utf8') as f:
    while True:
        chunk = f.read(chunksize)
        if not chunk:
            break
         compressed += gzip.compress(chunk.encode())

# I am able to use platforms internal file creation 
# process to create a zip with "compressed" variable - the issue here is that I cannot 
# reliably manipulate the data.
```

What I tried but does NOT work

```
import gzip
compressed = 'value,description,expiration,active\n'.encode()
with gzip.open('latest.json.gz', 'rt', encoding='utf8') as f:
    for line in f:
        obj = json.loads(line)
        data = f'{obj.get("ip")}{obj.get("organization")},,True\n'
            
        compressed += gzip.compress(data.encode())

# This code never seems to complete - I gave up after running for 3+ hours
```

**EDIT**
When I test the second example in an unconstrained environment it runs forever as well. However, if I modify the code like below to break after 10k lines it works as expected

```
... 
count = 0
for line in f:
    if count > 10000: break
    ...
    count += 1
```

Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: @larsks  It was a copy paste error - I have fixed it

Comment: In your second example, you should be setting `compressed = gzip.compress('value,description,expiration,active\n'.encode())`.

Comment: If you run this code in an unconstrained environment, does it work as written? That is, is the issue with the logic or with the resource constraints?

Comment: @larsks No it does not. The "Chunking" version does work but the second version where I manipulate the string does not work in an unconstrained env. 
However, If I limit the data by breaking out of the for loop after 10k lines it does work as expected

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but your `compressed += gzip.compress(whatever.encode())` is a terrible idea. That individually compresses each processed line into it's own gzip stream, and concatenates them all together. Each gzip stream will have 18 bytes of header and trailer overhead, plus poorly compressed, if compressed at all, data since the input is so short. You will likely expand the data instead of compressing it. You want to open a single gzip stream for writing, and then write each line to it.

Comment: How can a 2GB gzip file have less than 10,000 lines that look like your example gzip data? When you say that with the limit it "works as expected", do you mean it processes the entire file as you intended?

Comment: @MarkAdler I mean if I break the loop after 10k or 100k lines the script works and I get what I would expect. The full file has around 6.5 million lines

Answer (score 0):

Your `compressed +=` is the culprit. Python is copying `compressed` every time you concatenate to it. That takes O(*n k*) time instead of O(*n*), where *n* is the total size of the output and *k* is the number of pieces being concatenated. (Note that *k* is small for your 100MB chunks, but very large for your lines.) You need to write that data out or do something with it, instead of trying to accumulate it in a giant string in memory.

If you absolutely cannot avoid making a giant string in memory, then you will need to allocate space for the compressed data as a mutable array and copy it into that space instead of concatenating. In order to not have to know how big the result is ahead of time, once you get a compressed result that would exceed the space you have left, *double* the size of the space and then copy into that. So long as you double each time (or multiply the size by some factor), the time spent copying will be O(*n*).

The easiest approach in Python would be to use [BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO), which should do the above for you. Just write the compressed data to a string as if it were a file.

As I mention in a comment above, do *not* compress each little line separately as it's own gzip stream. You will not be compressing the data. You will be expanding the data. Instead create a [`zlib.compressobj`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html#compress-wbits), send the lines to that, and get the compressed data back as it's generated.

Comment: You were right, when I remove the concat line the entire script processes in ~30 seconds. Now the question is can I achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: I said how. Do what you need to do with each line, instead of accumulating it all in memory. Will this all be written to file? Then write the result from each line to the file. You already said you have limited memory compared to the data size, so why are you trying to store the entire result in memory?

Comment: The issue is that the script needs to run in a restricted env where I do not have direct access to the file system. In order to write to a file I have to pass the entire data set from memory. But the container I am running in will only have ~1GB of memory. 
So I need to find a way to compress the data on the fly in memory then write it out as such

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to do that, because the size of the converted gzip bytes will be greater than 1GB. If you remove curly braces, double quotes, colons, and keys from the decompressed text and recompress the converted text, the size will be near 100% of the original size, never close to 50%, because removed characters in each line do not change.

Anyway you can use the memory more effectively and compress faster by using the `GZipFile` stream like the following. (This compresses data only once as what Mr. Adler said.)

```
import io
import json
import gzip

bio = io.BytesIO()
N = 4000 # Number of lines sent to a compression stream at once. Experiment and find a good one.

with gzip.open('latest.json.gz', 'rt') as src_f, \
    gzip.GzipFile('latest.csv.gz', 'wb', fileobj=bio) as dst_f:
    lines = []
    def flush():
        if lines:
            dst_f.write((''.join(lines)).encode())
            lines.clear()
    def write(line):
        lines.append(line)
        if len(lines) >= N:
            flush()

    write('value,description,expiration,active\n')
    for line in src_f:
        obj = json.loads(line)
        write(f'{obj.get("ip")}{obj.get("organization")},,True\n')
    flush()

compressed = bio.getbuffer()
...
```

You can optimize this using two threads or processes if you can use multiple cores.(One for decompressing data and converting a JSON line to a CSV line, and the other for compressing data)